# Avoid an entity to be saved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've got two entities as follows:

```
@Entity
public class UserType implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userType")
  private List<User> users;

}
```

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_type")
  private UserType userType;

}
```

I don't want any new UserType to be created, this entity will have the same values the whole life of the project, but I still want it to exist as an entity so new Users only can be created if they are referencing an actual existing UserType.

With my current configuration, when I save a User that already exists (aka updating) pointing to a UserType that doesn't exist, the exception I recieve is EntityNotFoundException which seems ok, indicating me that this User can't be updated referencing a non existing UserType.
But, whenever I try to create a new User pointing to a UserType that doesn't exist, the exception is TransientPropertyValueException, which indicates me that Hibernate is in some way expecting this UserType to be saved.

That's how it's saved:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
}
```

```
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    public User update(User user, UserType userType, Integer id) {
      
      user.setId(id); //I'm updating an already existing entity.
      user.setUserType(userType);//value of userType id does not exists in database.
      user.getUserType().setUsers(List.of(user));
      userRepository.save(user); //this throws EntityNotFoundException

  }

    public User create(User user, UserType userType) { 

      user.setUserType(userType); //value of userType id does not exists in database.
      user.getUserType().setUsers(List.of(user));
      userRepository.save(user); //this throws TransientPropertyValueException
  }

}
```

Is this correct? Is there some way to avoid this behavior and to make it consistent so everytime I save User, no matter if I'm updating or inserting I receive the same exception?

Comment: Did you try to query UserType by id then set it to User entity also set user entities to userType?

Comment: I set the relationship in both sides before saving.

Comment: Did you query from database?

Comment: No, I just set the relationship before saving and let JPA to throw an exception about the UserType not existing in that case.What concerns me is that it behaves different when the User I'm creating is new, than when I'm updating.

Comment: Transient object mean there is no record of UserType in database. So it can not set id to column.

Comment: If you try to update you automatically query userType so there is no need to query it. It works as expected.

Comment: So why is that when I update the exception thrown is EntityNotFound?

Comment: How did you insert userType to begin with?

Comment: Just a SQL insert in database.

Comment: @Stgr please add the code that fails specifically so we can be able to help you

Comment: I added some code to illustrate where the fail happens. To clarify, the actual behavior is not opposed to what I want, as the User who holds a reference to a UserType that does not exist is not inserted nor updated, but it's confusing to me that two different exceptions are thrown in such similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think userType has to be queried and set it to User, if you don't want to create unnecessary UserTypes with cascade all.

I assume that userType is selected from combobox or similar ui component, so you need to get that UserType from database and set it to user entity which will be created.

Pseudocode :

```
UserType userType = userTypeRepository.findById(userType.getId());
user.setUserType(userType);
userRepository.save(user);
```